# How does this header handling work with CloudFlare?

Tags: http, header

Assuming I have my website which uses CloudFlare, can I set the `X-Forwarded-For` with another IP so it gets forwarded to my server?

I'm trying to do it with a tool and the website prints the IP I've set with `X-Forwarded-For`. How does this work?

Comment: How is this related to information security?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it's related to IP spoofing.

Comment: But my understanding of your question is that you ask only if you can set the header within Cloudflare and not how this can be misused, which is about as much security related as asking how to switch on a firewall. Maybe I understand your question wrong, but if you would just ask about the security impact of X-Forwarded-For then it would be on-topic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've replied the question. Check if there are some wrong things on that.

Comment: Your answer just describes how this header gets handled by Cloudflare. It does not describe which effect this behavior can have regarding information security. Therefore I think that in the current way neither question nor answer are on-topic here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've explained everything, as of now. Watch the edit.

Comment: The still cannot see a security problem asked in your question. And while your answer now explains why X-Forwarded-For can be a problem it does not explain why this  specific behavior of Cloudflare is a problem. Also, obviously Cloudflare changes the header if it exist so your quote (without reference!) does not apply here since it talks about spoofing the header by an attacker.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich could you do a further explanation to `Also, obviously Cloudflare changes the header if it exist so your quote (without reference!) does not apply here since it talks about spoofing the header by an attacker`? What do you mean "without reference"? What do you mean with `Cloudflare changes the header if it exist` (should be **exists**)?

Comment: You quoted two parts in your answer: the large one at the beginning from Cloudflare with reference and a smaller one at the end from an unknown source (still, can be found verbatim on the internet). That last quote refers to spoofing of the header by an attacker - which can not be applied directly here because if the header got spoofed by an attacker it will be changed again by Cloudflare as you correctly quote (*if there was ... header present... Cloudflare appends the client IP*)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, [it's pretty simple](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-CloudFlare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers):

> **X-Forwarded-For**
>
> X-Forwarded-For is a well-established HTTP header used by proxies,
>   including Cloudflare, to pass along other IP addresses in the request.
>   This is often the same as CF-Connecting-IP, but there may be multiple
>   layers of proxies in a request path.
>
> Two possible outcomes.
>
> First, if there was no existing "X-Forwarded-For" header in the
>   request sent to Cloudflare, then the header would have an identical
>   value to the CF-Connecting-IP header, like this:
>
> "X-Forwarded-For: A.B.C.D"
>
> where A.B.C.D is the client's IP address, also known as the original
>   visitor IP address.
>
> Second, if there was an "X-Forwarded-For" header present in the
>   request sent to Cloudflare, Cloudflare appends the client's IP to its
>   value, as the last in the list.
>
> "X-Forwarded-For: A.B.C.D[,X.X.X.X,Y.Y.Y.Y,]"
>
> where A.B.C.D is the client's IP address, also known as the original
>   visitor IP address. X.X.X.X and Y.Y.Y.Y in this example are IP
>   addresses along the route in the header value.

when you don't add the *X-Forwarded-For* header, CloudFlare will implicitly add it with the visitor's real IP address.

When you manually add with that header to your request another IP, the IP will be correctly spoofed in condition that Forwarding-For option is allowed from your server, and you'll be a *trusted forwarder*. To block *X-Forwarded-For* you can use iptables, or other.

In some cases, this header can be relevant to website's security.

> X-Forwarded-For HTTP header should not be used for any Access Control List (ACL) checks because it can be spoofed by attackers. Use the real IP address for this type of restrictions.